# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

for some reason I have been getting this error here and can't understand why. I have the array initialized, which is the reason for this error 99% of the time. I have both tried to initialize it with `private dashboardConversations: ChatDashboard[] = []` and the way you see below.

#### profile.component.ts

```
import { DashboardService } from '../../../pages/chatdashboard/_modules/dashboard.service';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 private dashboardService: DashboardService;

  @Input() public contact: Contact;

  public constructor(dashboardService: DashboardService) {
    this.dashboardService = dashboardService;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.image = this.contact.profilePicture;
    this._isAddInfoPresent();
    this.dashboardService.createNewConversation(this.contact);
  }
}
```

#### dashboard.service.ts

```
export class DashboardService {

  private dashboardConversations: ChatDashboard[] = new Array<ChatDashboard>();
  private bsDashboardConversations$: BehaviorSubject<ChatDashboard[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ChatDashboard[]>(this.dashboardConversations);

  public constructor(){}

  public activeConversations$(): Observable<ChatDashboard[]> {
    return this.bsDashboardConversations$.asObservable();
  }

  public createNewConversation(user: Contact): void {
    const newUser: ChatDashboard = {
      id: user.id,
      profilePicture: user.profilePicture,
      isImportant: false,
      lastMessageReceived: null,
      hasUnreadMessages: false,
      unreadMessages: null,
    };
    console.log('user before push', newUser); // all appropriate info is there
    this.dashboardConversations.push(newUser); //Error here
  }
}
```

#### dashboard.page.ts

```
  public conversations$: ChatDashboard[] = [];
  private dashboardService: DashboardService;

  public constructor( dashboardService: DashboardService){
    this.dashboardService = dashboardService;
  }
  public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dashboardService.activeConversations$().subscribe((conversations: ChatDashboard[]): void => {
      this.conversations$ = conversations;
    });
  }
```

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

edit: showed more code.

Comment: where does createNewConversation gets called from? and please show the subscription of bsDashboardConversations$. obviously dashboardConversations is getting nulled somewhere.

Comment: ok I'll post more information. It's that all the examples I've seen previously had to do with the declaration.

Comment: @Ctfrancia where are you calling `createNewConversation`? That's most likely the faulty code

Comment: @PierreDuc in a different service. I am calling it correctly because the information that is being sent to the function is there. I console logged the object before pushing it and the information is there correctly.

Comment: @Ctfrancia but... I'm asking how you are calling it, I'm pretty confident in the wrong matter, which makes you lose the `this` context of the service class. You can `console.log` the object you want to push, but the `this` is no longer the right `this`. Sooo, can you post the part where you actually call the `createNewConversation` method

Comment: @PierreDuc alright... I'll show more code

Comment: @Ctfrancia exciting! :D

Comment: @PierreDuc added more, but I can't see how. I am doing _literally_ the same thing the same type of BeaviorSubject with a different component/service and didn't lose `this` through a service. I cannot for the life of me how the refrerence of `this` is being lost. but hey, I have been wrong once (and only once) before 

Comment: @PierreDuc I have also hardcoded the object to push, and still the same error.

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(this)`. Put it below the other console.log you have there

Comment: and is there anywhere in your service you do `this.dashboardConversations = null;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194927/discussion-between-ctfrancia-and-pierreduc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You've not properly binded your `createNewConversation` method to whatever listener, so I guess the `this` context is lost</strike>

```
// examples on how to properly do it
.subscribe((user) => this.createNewConversation(user));
.addEventListener((user) => this.createNewConversation(user));
.then((user) => this.createNewConversation(user));
```

There are other ways like using `.bind(this)` or using a class field instead of a method

Maybe cleaning up the code and keeping to standards is going to help a bit:

#### profile.component.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public contact?: Contact;

  constructor(readonly dashboardService: DashboardService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.image = this.contact.profilePicture;
    this._isAddInfoPresent();
    this.dashboardService.createNewConversation(this.contact);
  }
}
```

#### dashboard.service.ts

```
export class DashboardService {

  private readonly bsDashboardConversations$: BehaviorSubject<ChatDashboard[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ChatDashboard[]>([]);

  readonly activeConversations$ = this.bsDashboardConversations$.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  public createNewConversation(user: Contact): void {
    const newUser: ChatDashboard = {
      id: user.id,
      profilePicture: user.profilePicture,
      isImportant: false,
      lastMessageReceived: null,
      hasUnreadMessages: false,
      unreadMessages: null,
    };

    this.bsDashboardConversations$.next([
      ...this.bsDashboardConversations$.getValue(),
      newUser 
    ]);
  }
}
```

#### dashboard.page.ts

```
  readonly conversations$ = this.dashboardService.activeConversations$;

  constructor(readonly dashboardService: DashboardService) {}
```

#### dashboard.page.html

```
<div *ngFor="let conversation of conversations$ | async"></div>
```

Comment: As he pointed out when I was fetching state the second parameter sets as `null` from TransferState

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `bsDashboardConversations$` inside `ngOnInit()` function

In the declaration, the value would not be initialized.